# Array prototype is read only, properties should not be added no-extend-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

So basically I have this code:

```
Array.prototype.inState = function (needle, haystack) {
  let index = this.findIndex(value => value[needle] === haystack);

  return index === -1;
};
```

and it works fairly enough to check if the given needle is exists in the react state or not. but ESlint keep saying that:

```
Array prototype is read only, properties should not be added  no-extend-native
```

so my question is: What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From EsLint Docs:

> In JavaScript, you can extend any object, including builtin or
>   “native” objects. Sometimes people change the behavior of these native
>   objects in ways that break the assumptions made about them in other
>   parts of the code.
>
> For example here we are overriding a builtin method that will then
>   affect all Objects, even other builtin.

```
// seems harmless
Object.prototype.extra = 55;

// loop through some userIds
var users = {
    "123": "Stan",
    "456": "David"
};

// not what you'd expect
for (var id in users) {
    console.log(id); // "123", "456", "extra"
}
```

In-short, `Array.prototype.inState` will extend the `array.prototype` and hence whenever you want to use an array, the instate function will be added to that array too.

So, in your case this example will be applied to array.

```js
Array.prototype.inState = function (needle, haystack) {
  let index = this.findIndex(value => value[needle] === haystack);

  return index === -1;
};


// loop through some userIds
var users = [{"123": "Stan"},{"456": "David"}];

// not what you'd expect
for (var id in users) {
    console.log(users[id]); // "123", "456", "extra"
}
```

**WorkAround**

---

You can add this line to ignore warning.

```
/*eslint no-extend-native: ["error", { "exceptions": ["Object"] }]*/ to ignore that warning.
```

Ref: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extend-native

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand this would be a good conversion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: With:

/*eslint no-extend-native: ["error", { "exceptions": ["Object"] }]*/ 

... It shows an error: 

"Failed to compile
./src/components/List/List.js
  Line 8:  Array prototype is read only, properties should not be added  no-extend-native
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error."

The proper solution/workaround is adding just:

// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native

...as Ashif Zafar said.

Answer (score 20):

Its because esLint gets it mutation to the native protoTypes chain.
You can add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native` in above the line it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable that rule on the whole project, just go to your eslint config file and add the following rule:

```
"no-extend-native": "off"
```